# Using sed or awk to remove near-duplicates

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk

I currently use the following to get as close as I can do to a file

```
cut -d ' ' -f 3- /var/log/issues.log | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}//g' | sort -u
```

So far it gets rid of the timestamp at the start of each line and removes the IP address.

However I'm still left with dozens of line of the format(s)

```
Failed login from for A
Failed login from for B
Failed login from for C
Failed login from for D
Failed login from for E
Invalid heartbeat 'A' from 
Invalid heartbeat 'B' from 
Invalid heartbeat 'C' from 
Invalid heartbeat 'D' from
Invalid heartbeat 'E' from
```

How would I further amend my command to take these "near" duplicates away leaving only. A, B, C, D and E could be any string.

```
Failed login from for 
Invalid heartbeat from
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the input data, and what is the output you are trying for. You might check [U&L]; if yours is a common use case, I'm guessing that someone has already asked there

Comment: Why not add `/Failed login from for/d;/Invaild heartbeat.*from/d` to your `sed` command?